# Let customers remove items from CartThrob packages

Tags: expresso-store, matrix, playa, cartthrob

I've got a setup on a site (currently running with CartThrob) where I need to select a Price Modifier (or Matrix) row via a Playa field, which I realise isn't possible with a hack.

There would be 100's of products (yarns and wools) and each would have several Price Modifier rows (colours). The colours are what I need to get to from the Playa field.

- Yarn 001 Red
- Yarn 001 Blue
- Yarn 001 Green
- Yarn 002 Red
- Yarn 002 Purple
- Yarn 003 Black

I need to create custom bundles of yarn colours.

I'm aware of the Packages field in CartThrob - but I need to be able to let the customer remove items from the bundle which doesn't look possible with CartThrob.

Could anyone tell me any different please?
Or can Store do this sort of functionality?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest forgetting about CartThrob and going with Brilliantretail.
I made few sites with ease! With color/size/style etc selection you can use sku number and so easy!
Their new and improved filtering system can be compared to overstock or amazon. Response time on page load with tons of products under 1 sec.